# Two servers can't communicate via MySQL Error Code(110)

Tags: php, mysql, web

I have a web server that I can manage via cPanel and I'm trying to connect to a MySql database on a dedicated server (running Ubuntu Server) that I manage. I have two tester connections that give the same error code (from web server to dedicated server).

`CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'IP_ADDRESS' (110)`

`Can't connect to MySQL server on 'IP_ADDRESS' (110)`

I also tried on my computer to connect to the dedicated server and I can do it. I'm using HeidiSQL as a GUI client to try connecting and I can connect to it with the same credentials.

What I have tried:
(I'm using Webmin to manage my mysql server)

- Set user host to Any
- Checked my.cnf for a bind address and it is bound to 0.0.0.0(all ips)
- Checked host permissions for specific databases and set the database to my test user and Any for hosts
- The Iptable should just allow all because after installing Ubuntu Server I have not changed anything.

I have no idea what else to try.

Comment: how is the webserver hosted?

Comment: I assume the string `IP_ADDRESS` is actually an IP address and not that string in your code. Because normally the error would display an actual IP address. Perhaps you could share the connection code just to look over the connection string and stuff like that.

Comment: @Dagon I'm not sure how the webserver is hosted. I just have access to the cPanel. Not much knowledge other than that.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn you're right IP_ADDRESS is the Ip to my box which I don't really want to share. 
But here is the connection

    <?php
    $servername = "IP_ADDRESS";
    $username = "multicraft";
    $password = "test";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    echo "Connected successfully";
    ?>

Comment: well the host could be blocking ports which will stop this working

Comment: Even on an outbound connection? Is there a way that i can test connecting to my server other than using a gui from my computer?

Comment: Without some sort of code or example, everyone would just be guessing. Outside of that, if you wanted to test the connection, start with making the most basic php script you can. Drop any classes you have written for db connection and go straight for making a connection using PDO or MySQLi. If that doesn't work, install the `mysql-client` package onto the web server and try to connect using that.

Comment: <?php
    $servername = "IP_ADDRESS";
    $username = "multicraft";
    $password = "test";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    echo "Connected successfully";
` ?> `

Comment: I can't format the code but that's what i'm using @JonathanKuhn.
I'm also using this site http://www.rainbowspuppiessunshine.com/tools/dbtest/ to try and test it